# android spinner not sizing properly

Tags: android, xml, layout, spinner

[image: My "details" linear layout with my spinner & two textviews.]

Above is a "details" linear layout I have in my app.  As you can see the spinner seems to dip down a bit more then the "Level 1" and "Per Level".  I have messed with the xml to try and get everything on a common base with out the spinner dropping down but I just cant figure it out.  I tried setting the spinners height to "fill_parent" and it does make it on the same base line but no text is shown inside the spinner.  Anyone have any ideas on what to do?

XML of the layout they are on:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/details"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/blank"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/levelOne"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/level_1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/perLevel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/per_level" />


        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

This is my XML for the text inside spinner:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:id="@+id/spinnerDisplay"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:textSize="12sp">

</TextView>
```

I use this inside of my Class to fill it in with the text size that I want:

```
spinLevels = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.LevelChosen, R.layout.spinner_item);      
spinLevels.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I just needed to remove "android:baselineAligned="false" from the details layout.

Answer (score 0):

On the `Spinner` in XML, add this line:

```
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
```

That should vertically center it in the layout.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked. What worked for me was the 'weights'

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
```